# How to get value as string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `tbl_Marks`:

```
Std_id  | sub_id  |  term_I   | term_2
--------+---------+-----------+-------
std_1   | 1       |   40      | 50
std_1   | 2       |   30      | 40
std_1   | 3       |   20      | 30
std_1   | 4       |   10      | 50

std_2   | 1       |   50      | 50
std_2   | 2       |   50      | 50
std_2   | 3       |   50      | 50
std_2   | 4       |   50      | 50
```

How can I get result like this:

```
Std_id  | sub_id  |  term_I   | term_2 | total  | status | PROMOTION_status
--------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------------
std_1   | 1       |   40      | 50     | 90     | PASS   | REPEATER
std_1   | 2       |   30      | 40     | 70     | PASS   | REPEATER
std_1   | 3       |   20      | 20     | 40     | FAIL   | REPEATER
std_1   | 4       |   10      | 50     | 60     | PASS   | REPEATER
```

Note : if total value is less than 50 of any sub_id

```
std_2   | 1       |   50      | 50     | 100    | PASS   | PROMOTED
std_2   | 2       |   50      | 50     | 100    | PASS   | PROMOTED
std_2   | 3       |   50      | 50     | 100    | PASS   | PROMOTED
std_2   | 4       |   50      | 50     | 100    | PASS   | PROMOTED
```

Note: if total value is greater than 50 or equal of each sub_id

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following SQL Select statement can help
Instead of [SQL CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) you can also use subselect statements
But the main trick in this query is using [MIN aggregation function with Partition by](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/count-and-row-number-function-for-n-of-m-rows-query.aspx) clause
This helps you to check if there is a lower than 50 mark for that student, if so it makes all records for that student as REPEATER status

```
;with cte as (
select  
*, 
term_1 + term_2 as total
from tbl_Marks
)
select
*,
case when (term_1 + term_2) >= 50 then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end as status,
case when (
min(total) over (partition by Std_id)
) >= 50 then 'PROMOTED' else 'REPEATER' end as PROMOTION_status
from cte
```

I hope it helps,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE`.

```
 select t.*,
        t.term_I + t.term_2 as total,
        case when t.term_I + t.term_2 >= 50 then 'pass' else 'fail' end as status,
        case when t.std_id = 'std_2' then 'PRMOTED' else 'REAPEATER' end as promotion_status
 from tbl_marks t
```

Comment: There are two type of std_id, one belong to repeater and another one belong to promoted... while executing query value returns repeater of both std_id

Comment: @NityanandVishwakarma check it now

Comment: Sorry for disturbing...
In case if std_id is more than 50, then what should Id do?
Please don't mind..
Because Std_Id will be more thatn 50....